# Parse string in objective c object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

How can I parse this into an objective-c object most efficiently?

"2010-07-13T11:22:33-07:00"

This is what I tried

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of object? I'm going to assume you want that to become an NSDate, in which case you want an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Come on, you can do better than that. WHAT have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];